# Does private link work for a lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a ECS fargate container running inside a private VPC which doesn't have internet access. It needs to invoke a lambda via AWS SDK. Based on my understanding, AWS creates a default public endpoint for the lambda and when I  call `invokeLambda` method the traffic will always go to internet. If my understanding is right, that means my Fargate container won't be able to call the lambda. Is it right?

If it is right, what is the alternative solution is? The goal is that the traffic won't go to internet in any chance.

- Can I create a private link endpoint for my lambda?
- Or create a API gateway with VPC endpoint which connects to lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If my understanding is right, that means my Fargate container won't be able to call the lambda. Is it right?

Yes. Without NAT gateway or instance, you won't be able to directly invoke the lambda function from private subnet.

> Can I create a private link endpoint for my lambda?

Sadly no. There are not VPC interface endpoints for lambda.

> Or create a API gateway with VPC endpoint which connects to lambda?

Yes, this should be possible by creating [private API gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html). The private API would be only accessible from within your VPC. But **API gateway to lambda will still probably go over the internet**.

The [Security Overview of AWS Lambda](https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Overview-AWS-Lambda-Security.pdf) whitepaper writes:

> Invocations from Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB streams, SQS queues, Application Load Balancer,and **API Gateway follow the request-response path**

> For **request-response invocations**, the payload passes from the API caller—such as AWS **API Gateway** or the AWS SDK—to a load balancer, and then to the Lambda invoke service. This service identifies an execution environment for the function, and passes the payload to that execution environment to complete the invocation. Traffic to the load balancer **passes over the internet**, and is secured with TLS.

Comment: Does VPC peering help?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I updated an answer, as I don't think there is any way to avoid internet.

Comment: for DynamoDB streams case, the lambda is pulling the data from stream rather than stream push data to lambda. So why does it require internet access?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I don't know why AWS's internal system were designed this way. Its a design choice that AWS made.